# What is the recommended pattern for dealing with global "Almost Constants"?

Tags: python, design-patterns, global-variables

I'm writing a bunch of functional tests and have a bunch of constants in a separate file.

I also have some "almost constants" in there.
These are initialized at  import time (result folders) or can be overridden by an environmental variable or cmdline flag during config just after start time

Is there any better design pattern for dealing with this sort of thing?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [configparser library](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/configparser.html). You can both write and read config files programmatically.